# how to put limits on marginleft jquery

Tags: jquery

How would I put limits on this slider.

I want to limit leftarrow to margin-left:0;
And right arrow to margin:-left:-500px;

would this be hard to do?

Any help appreciated.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/utKqe/2/

```
//other category page, navigate through cats
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#otherleftarrow').click(function() {
            $('#othermenu ul').animate({marginLeft: '-=100px'}, 200);
            return false; // prevent default click action from happening!
        });

        $('#otherrighttarrow').click(function() {
            $('#othermenu ul').animate({marginLeft: '+=100px'}, 200);
            return false;
        });

    });
```

Comment: @jdhartley posted the similar answer as mine, after I did, but mine's downvoted :-/

Comment: At first it works, but after random left/right clicking it bug, I think it may depends on the effective width of the animated div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#otherleftarrow').click(function() {
        if ( parseInt($('#othermenu ul').css('margin-left')) > -500 )
            $('#othermenu ul').animate({'margin-left': '-=100'}, 200);
        return false; // prevent default click action from happening!
    });

    $('#otherrighttarrow').click(function() {
        if ( parseInt($('#othermenu ul').css('margin-left')) < 0 )
            $('#othermenu ul').animate({'margin-left': '+=100'}, 200);
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#otherleftarrow').click(function() {
        $('#othermenu ul').animate({'margin-left': '-=100'}, 200);
        return false; // prevent default click action from happening!
    });

    $('#otherrighttarrow').click(function() {
        $('#othermenu ul').animate({'margin-left' : '+=100'}, 200);
        return false;
    });

});
```

Changes :
animate( {margin-left: '-=100' }) , instead of animate( {marginLeft: '-=100px' })

EDIT: Sorry I missed the quotes around margin-left, thanks for pointing out @YMMD

Comment: how is that different from the original?

Comment: his code has "px" and "marginLeft" , both are wrong. I removed both, sorry for not mentioning the changes.

Comment: And the hyphen between margin and left is also wrong without using quotes.

Comment: Even with those changes it doesn't solve the problem Sandro has.

Comment: @jdhartey, http://jsfiddle.net/AdNcW/2/ , a working example.
P.S : Not sure why the down-vote though :-/